# How to dynamically calculate the and restrict the width of a scrollable overflow div?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a horizontally scrollable div that renders some cards. There are buttons that, on click, transform the div left or right (back or forth).

The trouble I'm having is trying to figure out how to disabled the `Next` button, once the last card is reached. Disabling the `Back` button was simple, but this one, I'm having trouble with.

At the moment, it keeps scrolling right infinitely.

Here's the code,

```
import * as React from "react";

function getRandomNumber(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}

const cardWith = 200;
const cards = 10;
export default function Swipeable() {
  const [currentTransform, setCurrentTransform] = React.useState(0);
  const content = Array.from({ length: cards }, (_, index) => (
    <div
      style={{
        minWidth: cardWith,
        height: 300,
        backgroundColor: `rgba(${getRandomNumber(0, 255)},${getRandomNumber(
          0,
          255
        )}, ${getRandomNumber(0, 255)})`
      }}
    >
      card {index}
    </div>
  ));

  return (
    <div style={{ width: "100%", overflow: "hidden", position: "relative" }}>
      <div
        onClick={() => setCurrentTransform(currentTransform + 1)}
        style={{
          position: "absolute",
          right: 10,
          top: 100,
          cursor: "pointer",
          zIndex: 5,
          display: "grid",
          placeItems: "center",
          width: 50,
          height: 50,
          transition: "0.25s",
          backgroundColor: "cyan",
          borderRadius: "0.25rem"
        }}
      >
        Next
      </div>
      <div
        onClick={() =>
          currentTransform === 0
            ? undefined
            : setCurrentTransform(currentTransform - 1)
        }
        style={{
          position: "absolute",
          left: 10,
          top: 100,
          display: "grid",
          placeItems: "center",
          cursor: "pointer",
          zIndex: 5,
          width: 50,
          height: 50,
          transition: "0.25s",
          backgroundColor: "cyan",
          borderRadius: "0.25rem"
        }}
      >
        Back
      </div>
      <div
        style={{
          transition: "0.25s",
          display: "flex",
          transform: `translateX(-${currentTransform * cardWith}px)`
        }}
      >
        {content}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: boring-mendeleev-kqo98]

Answer (score 0):

I think got your desired result by just placing a condition on the Next button:

```
<div
    onClick={() =>
      currentTransform === 6
        ? undefined
        : setCurrentTransform(currentTransform + 1)
    }
...
```

To make it more beautiful maybe you can do a calculation with the widths, how exactly do you want it to be?

Comment: You can't just hard-code the number 6 in there because screens can be all different types of widths. Some may show 2 cards and some may show 10. You would definitely need to take that into account.

Comment: I was just about to say the same. I'm looking to find a way to do this dynamically. Thanks for the suggestion, though

Answer (score 0):

You just have to check the next index compared to the number of cards

```
function setCurrentTransform(index) {
    if (!index) {
        // If index is 0, disable the back button
        nextButton.disabled = false;
        backButton.disabled = true;
    } else if (index == cards) {
        // If index is the same as the number of cards, disable the next button
        nextButton.disabled = true;
        backButton.disabled = false;
    } else nextButton.disabled = backButton.disabled = false; // the index is somewhere between the start and end

    ...
}
```

Then your react render could be like this

Back button

```
<div onClick={
    () => setCurrentTransform(currentTransform - 1)
}
...
```

Next button

```
<div onClick={
    () => setCurrentTransform(currentTransform + 1)
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing you may want to consider instead of trying to make your own scrolling function is use [scrollIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView), combined with [getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect), which are built into browsers. This way, you could also remove `overflow: hidden` and use native scrollbars as well, or allow mobile swiping.

You would only need to store the current card in the state, and then increment it or decrement it when people click on the buttons to the next item that is not in the viewport. Instead of using translateX, you just use the browser's native scrolling.

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";

function getRandomNumber(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}

function isElementInViewport(el) {
  var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();

  return (
    rect.left >= 0 &&
    rect.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth)
  );
}

const cardWith = 200;
const cards = 10;

export default function Swipeable() {
  const refs = useRef([]);
  const [currentCard, setCurrentCard] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    refs.current = refs.current.slice(0, cards);
  }, []);

  const content = Array.from({ length: cards }, (_, index) => (
    <div
      ref={(el) => (refs.current[index] = el)}
      key={index}
      style={{
        minWidth: cardWith,
        height: 300,
        backgroundColor: `rgba(${getRandomNumber(0, 255)},${getRandomNumber(
          0,
          255
        )}, ${getRandomNumber(0, 255)})`
      }}
    >
      card {index}
    </div>
  ));

  const back = () => {
    for (let i = currentCard; i >= 0; i--) {
      if (refs.current[i] && !isElementInViewport(refs.current[i])) {
        setCurrentCard(i);
        refs.current[i].scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
        break;
      }
    }
  };

  const forward = () => {
    for (let i = currentCard; i < cards; i++) {
      if (refs.current[i] && !isElementInViewport(refs.current[i])) {
        setCurrentCard(i);
        refs.current[i].scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
        break;
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div
        style={{
          width: "100%",
          overflow: "hidden",
          position: "relative",
          whiteSpace: "nowrap"
        }}
      >
        <div
          style={{
            transition: "0.25s",
            display: "flex"
          }}
        >
          {content}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div
        onClick={forward}
        style={{
          position: "absolute",
          right: 10,
          top: 100,
          cursor: "pointer",
          zIndex: 5,
          display: "grid",
          placeItems: "center",
          width: 50,
          height: 50,
          transition: "0.25s",
          backgroundColor: "cyan",
          borderRadius: "0.25rem"
        }}
      >
        Next
      </div>
      <div
        onClick={back}
        style={{
          position: "absolute",
          left: 10,
          top: 100,
          display: "grid",
          placeItems: "center",
          cursor: "pointer",
          zIndex: 5,
          width: 50,
          height: 50,
          transition: "0.25s",
          backgroundColor: "cyan",
          borderRadius: "0.25rem"
        }}
      >
        Back
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-robinson-v9rm1?file=/src/Swipeable.js)